# ANDROID STUDIO: Where is the picture taken with Camera API stored locally? (NOT IN SD CARD)

Tags: android, view, android-studio, bitmap, android-camera

When I run this function in the Camera API

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture)
```

I wonder where this picture is "stored", and how I can access it. 
I dont mean stored like in saved in the SD card, but kinda like stored in a variable.

The picture is "frozen" on the screen after I take the picture with this function. I want to get this "frozen" picture as a bitmap, but dont know how. Or view, for that matter. Could anybody please help me with that?

Friendly regards,

Mathias Carlsen

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder where this picture is "stored",

It is not stored at all.

> how I can access it

The `byte[]` of the JPEG is handed to your `Camera.PictureCallback` (`mPicture` in your above code snippet).

> The picture is "frozen" on the screen after I take the picture with this function

It is more that preview is stopped, until you start it again.

> I want to get this "frozen" picture as a bitmap, but dont know how.

It should be fairly equivalent to the actual picture that was taken. You are also welcome to register for preview callbacks to get all preview frames handed to you.

Comment: How can I get the picture from the Camera.PictureCallback? 
It does just have the OnPictureTaken - method. 
I want a kind of; mPicture.getByteArray(), or mPicture.getBitMap() method :)

Comment: @MathiasLiaCarlsen: "How can I get the picture from the Camera.PictureCallback? It does just have the OnPictureTaken - method. " -- as I wrote, "the `byte[]` of the JPEG is handed to your `Camera.PictureCallback`". `Camera.PictureCallback` has one method, `onPictureTaken()`. That method has two parameters. The first parameter is the `byte[]`. "I want a kind of; mPicture.getByteArray(), or mPicture.getBitMap() method" -- sorry, but there is nothing like that in the Android SDK, for either the original `Camera` or the new `camera2` APIs.